# Angular 13 : Inheritance and polymorphism with Components

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, polymorphism, observable

My main problem is "how to render an Angular Form made from a parent Master Form ?".
Actually, I succeed on generating a "creational" form, in a way that you don't have a full object to display.
However, when I try to modify an existing element it's a nightmare.
It appears that the classical "patch" method, form the FormBuilder, is executed very lately after the view is created.
As the form view partially comes from the parent, the actual is not "refreshed".

Facing troubles with ngOnInit, a decided to remove it from parent. But problem still remains...
I could/should also have declared Parent class as "Abstract" but it leads to errors in the Child class. Angular / VSCode complains on the "app.module.ts" :

> Type 'typeof ParentCollectionsFormComponent' is not assignable to type
> 'any[] | Type'.   Type 'typeof ParentCollectionsFormComponent' is
> not assignable to type 'Type'.
> Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.

parent-collections-form.component.ts

```
 /**
 * Classe Mère d'affichage de formulaire d'une Collection
 * @param collectionIcon - string : Nom de l'icône affichée dans le titre du formulaire
 * @param elmtType - string : Le type de collection de l'élément à afficher
 * @param elmtName - string : La dénomination de l'élément manipulé
 * @param elmtID - number : L'identifiant unique, si existant, de l'élément manipulé.
 * en cas de fourniture d'un identifiant, le formulaire bascule en modification/update
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-collections-form',
  templateUrl: './parent-collections-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent-collections-form.component.scss']
})
export class ParentCollectionsFormComponent /*implements OnInit*/ {
  @Input() collectionIcon!: string;
  @Input() elmtType!: string;
  @Input() elmtName!: string;
  @Input() elmtID?: number;
  
  element!: CollectionParentModel;
  form?: FormGroup;

  @Output() onFormSubmitOrReject = new EventEmitter<CollectionParentModel | null>();

  constructor(protected readonly fb: FormBuilder, protected dbServ: DatabaseService) { 
    console.log("CONSTRUCTOR PARENT: ");
  }

  protected collectData() : void {
    console.log("PARENT COLLECTING...");
    this.dbServ.getID(this.elmtType, this.elmtID!).subscribe({
      next: (el: CollectionParentModel) => this.element = el/*; console.log(`ELEMENT IS ${JSON.stringify(this.element)}`);}*/,
      error: (err) => console.error(err),
      complete: () => {
        console.log(`Identical names ? ${this.element.name === this.elmtName}`, 'element: ', this.element);
        this.patchForm();
      }
    });

  }

  protected createForm() : void { }

  protected commitData() : void { }

  protected patchForm() : void { }

  /**
  * Traitement des données soumises dans le formulaire
  */
  async onFormSubmitted() : Promise<void> {
    if (this.form?.valid) {
      this.commitData();
      
      if (this.element.id === undefined) {
        //CREATE
        this.element.id === undefined;
        this.dbServ.create(this.elmtType, this.element).subscribe({
          next: (cm: any) => this.element.id = cm.id,
          error: (err) => { console.error(err); this.onFormSubmitOrReject.emit(null)},
          complete: () => this.onFormSubmitOrReject.emit(this.element)
        })
      } else {
        //UPDATE
        this.dbServ.update(`${this.elmtType}/${this.element.id}`, this.element).subscribe({
          //next: (p: Profile) => this.profile.id = p.id,
          error: (err) => { console.error(err); this.onFormSubmitOrReject.emit(null)},
          complete: () => this.onFormSubmitOrReject.emit(this.element)
        })
      };
    }
  }
  
  /**
   * En cas d'annulation du formulaire, emission d'un évènement 'null'
   */
  cancelledForm() : void  {
    //console.log('Canceled!');
    this.onFormSubmitOrReject.emit(null);
  }
}
```

challenge-form.component.ts

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'challenge-form',
  templateUrl: './challenge-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./challenge-form.component.scss']
})
export class ChallengeFormComponent extends ParentCollectionsFormComponent implements OnInit {
  challenge: ChallengeModel = new ChallengeModel;

  constructor(protected override readonly fb: FormBuilder, protected override dbServ: DatabaseService) { 
    super(fb, dbServ);
    console.log("CHILD");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("CHILD ON_INIT: ");
    of(this.createForm()).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        console.log('Creation finished');
        if (this.elmtID) {
        this.collectData();
        this.patchForm();
        };
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('CollectData ends here');
      }
    })
  }

  protected override createForm() : void {
    console.log('CHILD CREATE FORM');
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: [this.elmtName,[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(48)]],
      reward: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(28)]],
      requiredLevel: [0, [Validators.required]],
      rewardLevel: [0, [Validators.required]],
      step1Name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(48)]],
      step1Description: [''],
      step2Name: ['', [Validators.maxLength(48)]],
      step2Description: [''],
      step3Name: ['', [Validators.maxLength(48)]],
      step3Description: ['']
    })
  }

  protected override patchForm() : void {
    console.log('PATCH FORM!');
    this.form?.patchValue({
      name: this.challenge.name,
      reward: this.challenge.reward,
      requiredLevel: this.challenge.requiredLevel,
      rewardLevel: this.challenge.rewardLevel,
      step1Name: this.challenge.step1Name,
      step1Description: this.challenge.step1Description,
      step2Name: this.challenge.step2Name,
      step2Description: this.challenge.step2Description,
      step3Name: this.challenge.step3Name,
      step3Description: this.challenge.step3Description
    });
  }

  protected override commitData() : void {
    this.challenge.name             = this.form?.controls['name'].value;
    this.challenge.reward           = this.form?.controls['reward'].value;
    this.challenge.requiredLevel    = <number>this.form?.controls['requiredLevel'].value;
    this.challenge.rewardLevel      = <number>this.form?.controls['rewardLevel'].value;
    this.challenge.step1Name        = this.form?.controls['step1Name'].value;
    this.challenge.step1Description = this.form?.controls['step1Description'].value;
    this.challenge.step2Name        = this.form?.controls['step2Name'].value;
    this.challenge.step2Description = this.form?.controls['step2Description'].value;
    this.challenge.step3Name        = this.form?.controls['step3Name'].value;
    this.challenge.step3Description = this.form?.controls['step3Description'].value;
    this.element = this.challenge;
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I removed final part where I intended to collect general best practices.

Comment: In the present case, problem comes from the parent "element" that is not reachable in the child. (Don't know why). "element" becomes "challenge" in the child. But when I intend to cast in the child both objects are undefined.
I bypassed this issue passing the object "element" as a parameter of the "patchForm" method.

Comment: The updated method signature `protected override patchForm(challenge: ChallengeModel) : void`